# Problems while starting CRA with npm start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend

everyone! I run into some silly problem; every time I run `npm start`  I face the following error:

```
  events.js:288
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
  Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
```

One way of tackling this issue is to change  the following line `"react-scripts": "3.4.1"` in package.json to  `"react-scripts": "2.1.8"`
Why does that happen? It's really such a pain in the neck... any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: 1. What's your nodejs version?
2. Do you have create-react-app installed globally?
3. Try to `rm -rf node_modules && npm install && npm start`

Comment: I don't know why this happens in some Windows systems. I leave an upvote to your question. thanks.

Comment: Hey, @EliyaCohen. My Nodejs version is v12.16.1. Yes I have CRA installed globally. Some people are saying that it could cause an error. But my peers don't seem to run into the same issue...

Comment: Remove it from your global and use `npx create-react-app` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is my motto:

> For ridiculous issues, seek to find ridiculous solutions

Actually, it happens just because of your environment settings, you should set your Windows environment variable, _add `%SystemRoot%\system32` to your PATH, if it right, tell me to post it as an answer:

1. On the Windows desktop, right-click My Computer.
2. In the pop-up menu, click Properties.
3. In the System Properties window, click the Advanced tab, and then click Environment Variables.
4. In the System Variables window, highlight Path, and click Edit.
5. In the Edit System Variables window, insert the cursor at the end of the Variable value field.
6. If the last character is not a semi-colon (;), add one.
7. After the final semi-colon, type the full path to the file you want to find.

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\system32
   ```
8. Click OK in each open window
9. Restart System

Comment: Finally, Worked! I after the following the process described above, I just restarted my laptop and it worked. Thanks, @AmerllicA